# Создание нового окна в JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть главное окно, теперь понадобилось создать еще одно окно, которое создаю по нажатию на кнопку:

```
buttonCreateFunction.setOnAction(event -> {
    Label secondLabel = new Label("Label on new Window");
    StackPane secondaryLayout = new StackPane();
    secondaryLayout.getChildren().add(secondLabel);
    Scene secondScene = new Scene(secondaryLayout, 600, 400);
    // New window (Stage)
    Stage newWindow = new Stage();
    newWindow.setTitle("Second Stage");
    newWindow.setScene(secondScene);
    newWindow.show();       
          });
```

Контроллеры не использую, т.к. пока еще не умею с ними работать.
Как сделать, что бы весь код по работе с данным окном находился в другом классе, а еще лучше даже в двух классах, а то слишком большая портянка получается для одного класса

Comment: Создать `Controller` и привязать его к новому окну через fxml.

Comment: Т.е. в javaFX без контроллеров ни как не обойтись? Я просто при создании основного окна их ни как не использовал, вся реализация GUI была в обычном java классе

Comment: И я правильно понимаю, что в этом случае графическая чать будет описана в fxml?

Comment: Можно обойтись без контроллеров, но тогда кода будет больше. Вся GUI будет в fxml, верно. GUI часть можно делать в SceneBuilder.

Comment: я имел ввиду чтобы обойтись и без контроллера и без fxml. Я пока что не представляю как это все делается через связку контроллер-fxml. И документации толковой пока что найти не могу по этому вопросу. Или у меня не получиться получить доступ к этому окну из обычного java класса?

Comment: В контроллере могут находиться элементы и логика, которая относится к отдельному окну. Таким образом не надо писать все в одном классе или методе. Как вариант вы создание Вашего нового окна, без контроллеров и fxml можете просто вынести в отдельный класс. В нем создать окно и произвести нужные манипуляции.

Comment: https://metanit.com/java/javafx/2.2.php

Comment: а как можно получить доступ к этому окну и всем его элементам из обычного класса без контроллеров и fxml. Передав ему переменную newWindow объекта Stage в конструкторе?